# NH3.3 and Attaching detached object

Tags: .net, nhibernate, session

In the process of upgrading our entire system from NH1.2 to NH3.3.
A common scenario in the system (by previous developers) was to detach a number of objects and store them in the web Session, then attaching them at each request via a IHttpModule.

In a simple page load, running NHProf, i notice that these objects now being attached are causing triggering them to be updated in the database, although they have not been changed.

Previous code (NH1.2)to attach was along the lines of:

```
if (((NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl)session).IsSaved(obj)
   session.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)
```

Since it seems IsSaved has been removed the code is now:

```
if (obj != null)
   session.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)
```

My understanding was that LockMode.None should not result in a db update.
Some of the objects have versions, others do not.  Both a being updated.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the lock if actually doing what it should, but upon closing the session via the IHttpModule, NH is updating the DB as though the previously detached objects are now in the session - although they have not been changed anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I'll explain through an analogy, see the difference:

```
var obj = _nhibernateSession.Load<MyObject>(id);
obj.Title = "Some Title";
_nhibernateSession.Transaction.Commit();
```

and

```
var obj = someObjectInMemoryNotInSession as MyObject;
obj.Title = "Some Title";
_nhibernateSession.Update(obj);
_nhibernateSession.Transaction.Commit();
```

did you notice the difference: in first case an update is not required, because the obj is taken from session and the session will be aware of any change on it, but in the second example we require to call explicitly Update, because now our obj is detached from session.

Now to your question:
The statement:

```
if (((NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl)session).IsSaved(obj)
   session.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)
```

worked well in NH1.2, because in this way you were in first case(the case when the entity is loaded from session), but now you yse the second approach:

```
if (obj != null)
   session.Lock(obj, LockMode.None)
```

and it does not load the obj from session, that's why NHibernate it's triggering a database update.

If you want to avoid this just call Get() before if:

```
obj = session.Get(id, LockMode.None);
```

or simply:

```
obj = session.Get(id);
```

both will do the job for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Help me clear this up please in my mind. I understand your first two examples, and understand the Update tells NH it should track a detached object (if not mistaken). In the NH1.2 IsSaved if statement, a detached object would be saved = true, and therefore perform the Lock, as would the obj != null Lock statement, therefore doing the same thing. Or am I misunderstanding??

Comment: an Update will reattach the object and its properties that are lazy initialized may be accessed normally and the data is loaded lazy using the new session

Comment: lock mode is specified if the instance exists, which is not your case, you have only in memory object

Comment: Thanks. I think I will start to remove the detached objects as they are not my preference and call session.Load<T>(id) on the required at each request. Will make life much easier I think as well.